# What does well-isomorphic mean?

Tags: banach-spaces

What I'm currently reading discusses the notion of spaces being well-isomorphic, specifically a Banach space containing well-isomorphic copies of $\ell_1^n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The author doesn't define this, so I gather it's an elementary definition, but I gather that it means for every $n$ we have a linear operator $T_n$ such that $\| x\| \leq \|T_nx\|\leq D\|x\|$ for some $D\in(0,\infty)$.

However, the only place I've actually found a definition stated is in Isomorphisms Between H1 Spaces, by Paul Muller, who just gives the requirement that $\|T_n^{-1}\|\|T_n\| <\infty$. The definition that the author of the paper I'm reading seems to be using is stronger, I think, since we don't have any constant in front of the first $\|x\|$ in the inequality. It seems that we also need to know that $\|T_n^{-1}\|=1$.

What is the proper definition?

Edit: I'm reading "An Introduction to the Ribe Program", by Assaf Naor. It's publicly available. The passage I'm considering is at the bottom of page 17.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing your \mathcal{l} to \ell. I thought the \mathcal{l} didn't look particularly different from the ordinary lower-case form. $\qquad$

Comment: No problem. Thanks!

Comment: $\ldots\,$Actually, it looked identical to the ordinary lower-case form $\qquad$

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say that your partial definition has the quantifiers backwards. I.e., it ought to be “there is some $D$ so that for every $n$ …”. The lack of a constant in front of $\|x\|$ is likely not a problem, as you can always rescale $T_n$ so that constant becomes $1$. (The constant on the other side – $D$ – will have to pay the price.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I suspect it you're correct and it must be something like that. I see how we could rescale any particular $T_n$ so that it works, but could we rescale all of them so that fixed $D$ still works?

Comment: Well, what I am saying is that if the inequalities were given as $C\|x\|\le\|T_nx\|\le D\|x\|$ for all $n$, then you can rewrite that as $\|x\|\le\|C^{-1}T_nx\|\le C^{-1}D\|x\|$, so replacing $T_n$ by $C^{-1}T_n$ and $D$ by $C^{-1}D$, you have the inequalities stated in the question.